# If ComboBox on Form is blank, Then

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access that displays employee information. One of the fields on the form is a ComboBox called ReportsTo.

I'd like to create a macro that says if this particular field is blank, an error message should pop up.

I've tried a number of differed 'If' statements, but can't get anything to work.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
If Len([Forms]![Employee Form]![ReportsTo]) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Error on this field"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would try: If (Trim([Forms]![Employee Form]![ReportsTo].value) = "") OR (IsNull ([Forms]![Employee Form]![ReportsTo].value))Then

Comment: Better yet, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929186/combobox-null-in-if-statement

Comment: Ok will try in about 30 minutes or so. Should I keep using the AfterUpdate or something else?

Comment: ok, so same issue. This macro will work if I manually run it, but I would like it to run in the background automatically. Basically, if the user goes to a record where this field is blank, the message should automatically pop-up.

Comment: Then use the `On Current` event.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!